# Converting list of maps into list of lists

Tags: apex, list

we are getting the list output values below

```
({1=huffs, 2=45}, {1=huffy, 2=49}, {1=huff, 2=44}, {}, {})
```

I want the output as below
for example:

```
({huffs,45}, {huffy, 49}, {huff, 44}, {}, {})
```

Comment: The way it's currently written it looks like a map and not a list. Can you please update the question with the corresponding type of the collection?

Comment: I cant understund your problem. Can you explain it a litle more?

Comment: my list output is= ({1=huffs, 2=45}, {1=huffy, 2=49}, {1=huff, 2=44})

Comment: my list output is= ({1=huffs, 2=45}, {1=huffy, 2=49}, {1=huff, 2=44}),I need remove index of 1,2 in array

Comment: @Nikitha does the solution below fit yor scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection seems to be a list of maps. If it's just some json string, make sure to make a list of maps of it. Then try this:

```
public List<List<Object>> DoTheJob(List<Map<Integer,Object>> myMapList){

    List<List<Object>> resultList = new List<List<Object>>(); // your result list of lists

    for(Map<Integer,Object> m : myMapList)
    {
        List<Object> myTupple = new List<Object>();
        for (Integer key : m.keySet()) 
        {
            myTupple.Add(m.get(key));
        }
        resultList.Add(myTupple);
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

This should do the trick. `myMapList` is your input collection here (`{1=huffs, 2=45}, {1=huffy, 2=49}, {1=huff, 2=44}, {}, {}`). I think you should remove empty elements first. Make sure to make your collection to be in form of `List<Map<Integer,Object>>`.

The result is a list of lists, where each internal list is in the form of `{"huff", 45}`.

Comment: global static pagereference newlineSave(list<string>valuefromJSNewdata){ system.debug('Table2-valuefromJS---->'+valuefromJSNewdata);  }               DEBUG|Table2-valuefromJS---->({1=mu, 2=4}, {1=mu, 2=4}, {1=mu, 2=4}, {1=mu, 2=4}, {})

Comment: OK, it seems to be JSON collection. So, make a list-of-maps of this collection, and then use the method I wrote above. Please mark my answer as correct if it fits your requirements.