# Salesforce Get Map of list into one List

Tags: apex, list, map

Below is my map. Looking for shortest way to get everything into list.

```
Map<String,List<User>> permSetNameUserMap;
List<user> userList = permSetNameUserMap.Values(); //This is wrong becoz its list<List<user>>
```

Any Idea to store into userList fastest way ? (possible of not using loop)

Comment: You have to use a for Loop

Comment: this post may helps http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93226/converting-list-of-maps-into-list-of-lists

Answer (score 4):

You have to loop through the map:

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();
for (String key : permSetNameUserMap.keySet()){
    userList.addAll(permSetNameUserMap.get(key));
}
```

and use `addAll` for each list value.